# How flexible is the syntax of static pattern rules in Make?

Tags: makefile, reproducible-research

I'd like to use make as a tool for reproducible research.  This research involves a long pipeline which I will run for many independent datasets, requiring a workflow that I'll describe in "pseudo-make" as follows:

```
datasets = foo bar baz

$(datasets): path/to/result/%.dat: 
    ./generate_dat_from %

$(datasets): path/to/figs/%.png: path/to/result/%.dat
    ./generate_png_from_dat path/to/result/%.dat

[etc.]
```

If make were to simply substitute the name of each dataset for '%', this would be exactly what I want.  However, the GNU make manual has this to say about [the syntax of static pattern rules](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/make_4.html#SEC38):

> When the target-pattern matches a target, the `%' can match any part of the target name; this part is called the stem. The rest of the pattern must match exactly.

Which explains why the code sketched above doesn't work.  What is the best way to accomplish this in make, or is make simply not the right tool for this job?

Thanks in advance, and apologies if the question is poorly put-- I'm new to make and barely sure of how to express this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured this out.  The problem was in the following line:

```
./generate_dat_from %
```

which is an illegitimate use of '%'.  The correct form is:

```
$(datasets): path/to/result/%.dat: 
./generate_dat_from $*
```

where $* captures whatever was matched by % in the target.

Hope this is useful to others.